# FileUpload virus protection of server

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, antivirus

My ASP.NET Application has an FileUpload control. My server doesn't have any antivirus program. If I add a byte to binary content of the file before saving file, does my server affect from virus? When displaying file, I will remove extra byte from the content.

Thanks for replies.

Comment: I don't think there's much of a risk anyway because uploaded files don't generally have the opportunity to execute.

Comment: There are some jpeg viruses. Non executable files can have a virus.

Comment: Then how about renaming all uploaded files with the extension `.resources` so they can't be opened/run? You can still read the data and serve it to the client using ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A virus will only cause you problems if it is run on the server (i.e. the file is opened). You can get around this by renaming all uploaded files with a `.resources` extension. All requests for this type of file are sent by IIS to ASP.NET, which rejects them. So effectively, the files store the data but can't be opened/run at all. Then you can still serve them back by reading their content in an ASP.NET page/module, and returning the data as a file with the correct extension.

Transforming the data as you suggest will also provide a level of protection, though I'd probably do more than add a byte to the end. Perhaps run the whole stream through a reversible algorithm (e.g. a fast encryption or something).

Of course, this doesn't protect the client from any virus.